# Jint: using CLR object 's properties in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, .net, jint

I have been testing the jint library and hit a snag. Given this class in C#:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Bar";
}
```

And this code:

```
Engine engine = new Engine(x => x.AllowClr());

object rc = _engine
    .SetValue("foo", new Foo())
    .Execute("foo.Name.startsWith('B')")
    .GetCompletionValue()
    .ToObject();
```

I get the error: 'Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException: 'Object has no method 'startsWith'''

This works, however:

```
"foo.Name == 'Bar'"
```

So can I get the former to work?

Comment: Should it be the uppercase? .StartsWith

Comment: Neither StartsWith (.NET) nor startsWith (JS) work

Answer (score 0):

Support for extension methods is added [here](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/pull/616). But can't get it to work with the .NET string extension methods directly, it does work with an intermediate extensions class.

**Update**: The string methods like `StartsWith` aren't real extension methods indeed.

Looks like startsWith is already supported natively now. Replaced `GetCompletionValue` with the suggested `Evaluate`

```cs
// Works natively with Jint 3.0.0-beta-2032
Engine engine = new Engine();

bool result = engine
    .SetValue("foo", new Foo())
    .Evaluate("foo.Name.startsWith('B')")
    .AsBoolean();
```

I've tried to add the `string` extension methods, but that doesn't seem to work. But using your own class for the extension methods and use it that way does work.

```cs
public static class CustomStringExtensions
{
    public static bool StartsWith(this string value, string value2) =>
      value.StartsWith(value2);
}

Engine engine = new Engine(options =>
{
    options.AddExtensionMethods(typeof(CustomStringExtensions));
});

bool result = engine
    .SetValue("foo", new Foo())
    .Evaluate("foo.Name.StartsWith('B')")
    .AsBoolean();
```

I've asked about the native extension methods support [here](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/issues/1064), as I'm curious if and how it is supposed to work.